# From a query, place the information in horizontal manner on a table

Tags: php

I have the following query:

```
$res = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM books",$conexion);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))

echo $row["Name"];
```

I want to place it in horizontal manner in a table like this:

```
Name1 Name2 Name3 Name4
Name5 Name6 Name7 Name8
Name9 Name10 Name11 Name12
```

instead of

```
Name1
Name2
Name3
Name4...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you an idea of what you need to look at.  Basically you are looping through the results you have collected and displaying them inside a table row.  Each result will be inside it's own cell within the row.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <?php 
    foreach( $result as $key )
    {
      echo "<td>$key</td>";
    }
    ?>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You will need to adjust the array supplied `$array` but it is the basis of what you need.